# Hosting Neo4j in GCP Compute engine

Tags: java, web-services, neo4j, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to host a Neo4j web service for a Wikipedia graph of pages and categories and basically get some recommendations out via cypher queries.
I have already created and populated the database.

**How do I “ideally” setup such a service ?**

- Should I keep 1 dedicated instance for the Neo4j server and separate
  instances for running Tomcat or Jetty which receive the client’s
  requests and then forward the request to the Neo4j server instance
  via the REST API ?
- Or directly send requests (cypher via REST) from the client to the 1 neo4j instance ?
- Or should I choose unmanaged extensions provided my Neo4j ?
- Or is there any other way to set it up keeping scaling in mind?

I do plan to run load balancing and HA clusters in the future.

The web service will be accessed by browsers and mobile apps.

I have never hosted such a web service before so it would be great if someone helps me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you create an API app that sits between your clients and Neo4j. Your clients would make requests to the API server, which would then make a Cypher request to Neo4j (could be one instance or an HA cluster).

The benefits of this include being able to implement caching at the API layer, authenticate requests before they hit your database server, being able to instantly update Cypher queries by deploying to the API server (imagine if the Cypher logic lived in your mobile app - you would be at the mercy of app store / user upgrades), and easily scaling your API by deploying more API servers.

I've skipped this layer and just used unmanaged extensions to extend the Neo4j REST API and have clients access Neo4j directly which works OK for rapidly implementing a prototype, but you lose many of the benefits listed above with one additional downside that you will have to restart your database in order to deploy new versions of the unmanaged extension.

Comment: Thanks that clears it for me :) And should I use JDBC or the REST API  to communicate to the Neo4j server from the API app server that sits between my clients and Neo4j ? In terms of speed and performance which approach will be faster: JDBC or the Neo4j server REST API ?